# What are these type of words called?

Tags: grammar, verbs

What do you call a verb after adding the endings ***-or***, ***-ant***, ***-ent***, or ***-er*** to it? The new word refers to the thing or the person who did the verb. Should I call it adjective or participle or what?

Consult --> Consultant

Assist --> Assistant

Study --> Student

Create --> Creator

Work  --> Worker

Play --> Player

Write --> Writer

Maybe: be --> beings

Comment: These are *nouns*.

Comment: @Andrew What if I wanted to ask a native English speaker about a specific verb? Should I say: "What's the noun of the verb play?"

Comment: @Andrew I expect the answer to be (Player) but I think they may reply by saing (Playing) or something else. So I think I need to specify what type of nouns are these. Am I right?

Comment: @Andrew If there's no term in English that defines them. What's the shortest way to explain it?

Comment: Yes, you would say something like *"Whats' the noun for a person who plays?"* or other variations.   Although I do expect there is some term used by linguists for something like *"the noun to describe the person who does some verb"*  but I have no clue what that would be, as it's likely a technical term known only to people in that field.

Comment: That being said, the *-ing* form of a verb that turns it into a noun is called a *gerund*, but that's different from what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the resulting words in your list are **nouns**, even if they are built "on-top of verbs".

Actually, the word and the noun are part of a family of words, all of them having the same root.

Example: **to play, play (n.), player, playing, playful**. They are all in the same family, built on the root "play".

As pointed out by **@user2824371**, these nouns are called [**agent nouns**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun).

Also answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/367704/which-category-of-nouns-do-driver-cleaner-writer-processor-belong-to).

Comment: So can I call them "Agent nouns" as stated in this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun

Comment: If I said "Doer nouns", is this more understandble?

Comment: but it seems that the name "Agent nouns" is not common. Not every native English speaker identifies it, right?

Comment: but "doer nouns" - where did you get that?

Comment: to a non-native English speaker, a lot of details of the English language are "uncommon". We have to live with it.

Comment: "doer nouns" is just the literal translation of what we call it in my mother tongue language.

Comment: A rule which I learned even better after I moved to another country because of job: never judge a language using a different language. Especially, never judge (or learn) a "new" language using your own native language. You will always get into dead-ends. Just accept the foreign language as it is.. You will surely not make it better (neither me, for that matter).

Comment: I mean if I said to a native English speaker: "Would you tell me the agent noun of play?" Can they simply understand what I mean? or Do they have to be experts in the language or linguistics to understand what I'm trying to say?

Comment: If the native English speaker has a good mastery of the theory of the English grammar, he will understand. Otherwise, he will probably not. It is the same in your language or my language. Some people know some things, some other people know other things, and some other people know nothing. It is life. It always depends on who you are talking to.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much virolino for your help and for taking time to answer my questions. That is really appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to ask questions whenever you need. If I will not be available to answer, somebody else will be.